# Не могу подключить jquery в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Учу по книге javascript для детей и вот ступор просто. Просто не работает, не понимаю почему.

```html
<html lang="ru" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DOM</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="main-heading">Привет всем!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js">
    var newHeadingText = prompt("Введите новый заголовок:");
    $("#main-heading").text(newHeadingText);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А как вы понимаете, что не работает? Наверное, потому что `prompt` не выполняется? Вам надо ваш код `var newHeadingText = ...` перенести в отдельный тег `script`, у которого не будет `src`. Читайте книгу внимательнее!

Comment: Насколько я знаю, если в теге ```script``` указать ```src```, то его содержимое будет игнорироваттся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у тега `script` задан атрибут `src`, все содержимое которое находится внутри тега игнорируется